# HTML Agility pack why does not the HTML page get to string?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Error "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectSingleNode(...) return null."
My exemplary code.

```
            string url = @"http://www.baza-firm.com.pl/?vm=zabrze&pg=2&b_szukaj=szukaj";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        //Process.Start(url); //wyswietlenie strony
        var doc1 = web.Load(url);

        MessageBox.Show(doc1.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.ToString());


        var nazwa = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='przeppoz']").InnerText;
        var ulica = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@itemprop='streetAddress']").InnerText;
        var kod_pocztowy = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div/span[@itemprop='postalCode']").InnerText;
        var miejscowość = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div/span[@itemprop='addressLocality']").InnerText;
        var wojewodztwo = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div/span[@itemprop='addressRegion']").InnerText;
        var telefon = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='divSMV_tel1 clearBoth']");
        List<string> lista_tel = new List<string>();
        foreach (var node in telefon)
        {
            lista_tel.Add(node.InnerText);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("nazwa " + nazwa
                        + "\nkod pocztowy " + kod_pocztowy
                        + "\nulica " + ulica
                        + "\nkod pocztowy " + kod_pocztowy
                        + "\nmiejscowość " + miejscowość
                        + "\nwojewództwo " + wojewodztwo
                        + "\ntelefon " + lista_tel[0].ToString());
```

Previously worked now shows a empty page. Why does not work Agility pack?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Please read it, and understand what he is saying. You need to make an attempt to debug it yourself, start taking pecies out till it works again, then when it works try to figure out why the last thing you took out broke it, if you can't then come back here and ask a specific question about why that peice you took out broke the code when you put it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server returns `404 - Not Found` as a response status, but also returns the html content you expect.

So, by changing the downloading code a little bit, your parsing code works...

```
string url = @"http://www.baza-firm.com.pl/?vm=zabrze&pg=2&b_szukaj=szukaj";
var doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var resp = await client.GetAsync(url);
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
    var html = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    doc1.LoadHtml(html);
}


MessageBox.Show(doc1.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.ToString());
.....
......
```

Comment: Thank you. Please explain how the program works now

Comment: @dawid653 `web.Load` seems not to read the content when server returns an error code. I just used httpClient's *GetAsync* method which behaves differently.

Comment: How to return Task<String[,]> ? 
<code>
class nowa 
{ 
public async Task<String[,]> co() 
{ 
    ... 
    return table; 
} 
private void  button2_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nowa nw = new nowa();

            Task <String[,]> wy = nw.co();

            //MessageBox.Show(wy[0,0]);
            string a =  wy[0, 0]; //error
        }
</code>